# Is there a template to insert querys?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a few certain values from a php file, to my MySQL database, using a query.
I use the following code snippet:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `text` VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$text', '"$categories"')");
```

but I get an error saying the following:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Func\idea.func.php on line 10

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I have stated both variables, earlier, by making them into real escape strings. My MySQL table structure is as follows:

```
idea_id (auto)
user_id 
text
categories
timestamp
```

Comment: `$categories` is wrapped in double quotes; remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `text` VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$text', '" . $categories . "')");
```

or get rid of the double quotes surrounding $categories:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `text` VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$text', '$categories')");
```

Comment: Note that there is a small performance hit with the second method

Comment: glad to hear it NorS!

thanks for the info, waitinforatrain. I only added it for consistency's sake, since he had $text that way, but that's good to know

Comment: You should use single quotes, then, to avoid the parser having to scan for interpolation _at all_.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer

```
mysql_query(sprintf(   
  "INSERT INTO `text` VALUES ('', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
  mysql_real_escape_string($user_id),
  mysql_real_escape_string($text),
  mysql_real_escape_string($categories)) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `'"$categories"')")` to   `'" . $categories . "')"`.

You need to put fullstops between the variables to tell PHP that you want to concatenate (join) all of it together as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Point is very important in this case it serves to separate the two variables in this case. If there is no point return error